# (Swift/XCODE) Creating multiple segues from a single table view controller

Tags: swift

I am new to programming in Swift and I having the hardest time trying to figure out how to connect a static table view with 6 cells to 6 separate dynamic prototype views.

From looking at previous responses, I know that I have to identify each segue ("showRestaurant") and I thought it would go in the override segue method but I am not sure. I am also unsure of how to properly code it.

Please let me know if you have any solutions

Thanks so much

Diamond

Answer (score 0):

With a static tableView you can simply ctrl-drag from the tableViewCell to the destination viewController. Choose the type of the segue and give it an identifier (i.e. *segueToVC1*).

Repeat that for each tableViewCell which should be linked to a viewController.

Then in your custom tableView class file you override `prepareForSegue` to do additional setup, passing values to the destination viewController etc:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueToVC1" {
        // ...
    }
}
```